# Create an empty vector with certain size in DolphinDB

Tags: dolphindb

In Python, I can create an empty list like this:

```
a = [None] * 5
```

But in DolphinDB, when I tried to run this:

```
a = take(NULL, 5)
```

the interpreter just gave the error message:

> Not allowed to create void vector

So how can I create an empty vector with all elements being NULL?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?VectorSetTupleWithNULLs.html

Comment: Thank you. But the help doc merely gives examples where some elements in the vector are NULL. What I want is to create an all-NULL vector

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it in this way:

`array(int, 100, 100, NULL)`

or

`bigarray(double,10000000,10000000,NULL)`

where `NULL` is the default value filled in the vector.

[check this out](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/array.html)